# HibernateQueryException: unexpected token inside a number

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I get a HibernateQueryException from this Query. The innerQuery returns a legit number (0194) but the outerQuery throws the exeption. I cannot see any error in the syntax. Also strange is that the parseing Exception starts within the middle of the number.

```
String innerQuery = "select barcode from Data where barcode is not null";
List<String> innerResults = getHibernateTemplate().find(innerQuery); //returns a List with one item "0194";
    if(!innerResults.isEmpty()){
        String outerQuery = "from Data d where d.barcode in (" +
        innerResults.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "") + ")";
        return getHibernateTemplate().find(outerQuery);
    }
```

Exception

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: 
    unexpected token: 94 near line 1, column 35 [from Data d where d.barcode in (0194)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the first results is fixing the problem. As a concat inside the HQL returns always the same string and not the selected values I quote the results afterwards.

```
String innerQuery = "select barcode from Data where barcode is not null";
List<String> innerResults = getHibernateTemplate().find(innerQuery);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String barocde : innerResults){
    results.add("'" + barcode + "'");
}
if(!results.isEmpty()){
   String outerQuery = "from Data d where d.barcode in (" +
   results.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "") + ")";
   return getHibernateTemplate().find(outerQuery);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have stored `barcode` field as String (0194), so you must quote your values.

So you can apply this fix:

```
String innerQuery = "select concat(''', barcode, ''') from Data where barcode is not null";
```